# Avoid duplicate formatting between server-side Razor view and client-side jQuery template

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-templates

I have a search results page where I output a list of items formatted in a particular way using a MVC Razor view.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++) {
  <div class="result">
    <div class="ordinal">@((i+1).ToString()).</div>
    <div class="detail"><p>@group.ElementAt(i).Name</p></div>
  </div>
}
```

The client can further filter those results using jQuery AJAX to retrive a new dataset as JSON and jQuery templates to render the resultset in place of the original. This is the jQuery Template:

```
<script id="resultTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  {{each(i, result) results}}
    <div class="result">
      <div class="ordinal">${i+1}.</div>
      <div class="detail"><p>${name}</p></div>
    </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

which is bound after AJAX call:

```
var result = $("#resultTemplate").tmpl({ results: data });
$("#resultsColumn").empty().append(result);
```

Note how I had to duplicate the HTML formatting for a search result in both server-side Razor code and client-side jQuery code. I'd like to have just one version of the data bound template to reduce the chance of mismatches when I have to make changes.

Reading [Stephen Walter's Intro to jQuery Templates](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx) he's hinting at "better together" integration when using jQuery templates with ASP.NET MVC so I was wondering if there's a facility that addresses the above scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use the `@helper` syntax to avoid some of the duplicated markup.

```
@helper Result(string ordinal, string name) {
    <div class="result">
        <div class="ordinal">@ordinal.</div>
        <div class="detail"><p>@name</p></div>
    </div>
}
```

Then use the helper for both the Razor view

```
@for (int i = 0; i < group.Count(); i++) {
    @Result((i+1).ToString(), group.ElementAt(i).Name)
}
```

and the jQuery template

```
<script id="resultTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    {{each(i, result) results}}
        @Result("${i+1}", "${name}")
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

That's assuming your jQuery template resides in the Razor view itself.

On the downside, you have to convert every argument to string before passing them to the helper. And, for some reason, passing `"${i+1}"` to the helper feels plain wrong.

I'm not sure yet I would use that kind of approach in production, but I guess it depends on the complexity of the markup involved.

Comment: This should work for simple templates and I agree that it becomes unwiedly for complex templates (in reality my jQuery template uses composition, the above is a simplified example). It would've been nice if Razor and jQuery templates would share common syntax, except that would annoy the PHP crowd ;) and would pretty soon run into limitations as you start using more specific language constructs.

Answer (score 0):

You could render the initial search result with the same jquery template instead of using the razor syntax, this avoids the duplication. You could put this in the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#resultTemplate')
    .tmpl(@group.ToJson()))
    .appendTo("#resultTemplate");
</script>
```

I made up the ToJson method on the group object. It could be a method you implement on your viewmodel or whatever the group var is coming from to serialize the collection to json.

Comment: True, but this is not SEO. I would've done the entire search results functionality on the client-side if it weren't for those damn search bots who won't run JS ;). Plus I need to have something show up for the few visitors w/o JS.